# Не-перекати-поле

Tags: орфография

В РАН написано, что, если мы делаем с помощью *не* новое существительное, его надо писать с этой частицей слитно, напр.: *Я какого-то некота увидел, бежа вперёд да прочь.* Там, однако, также говорят, что любые образования, дефис имеющие, с *не* раздельно пишутся. Но если я хочу сделать сущесвительное с *не* и оно имеет дефис? Надо тогда *не* дефисом прибавлять? Как правильно?

`Сэр, простите, но то, что вы держите, – это какое-то не-перекати-поле.`

`Сэр, простите, но то, что вы держите, – это какое-то не перекати-поле.`

Comment: Не думаю, что некот - это корректно. Не употребляется только с понятиями, из кота тяжело сделать понятие. Не поле, не шкаф, не река, не молоко - только так. Немолоко - разве что как бред-сленг тянет.